# How to use mtmm function r package psy without generating plot?

Tags: r

I am building a shiny app in which I want to be able to display the item subscale correlations data frame generated by the mtmm function of the psy package. I only need the data frame, but the function will generate a plot as well.

Is there a way of making mtmm() stop automatically generating the plot?

For an example of the function you can do this:

```
library(psy)
par(mfrow=c(1,5))
mtmm(ehd,list(c("e15","e18","e19","e20"),c("e4","e5","e6","e14","e17"),c("e11","e13","e16")
,c("e1","e10","e12"),c("e2","e3","e7","e8","e9")))
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to "hack" it, as I don't see any built it option to do this

Comment: I was afraid so :-). If there's no simple way, I will take a look at the function code.